# Blackjack.java while loop input validation

Tags: java

I am creating a simple Blackjack java program and I am stumped with the while loop input validation. When a user is requested to draw a card, he/she has the option: (y/n) to choose from as well as if they want to play again. My problem is when I am prompted to draw a card and I choose y, that character only should prompt a card draw...but it seems as if any character would do that trick. The same goes for the  play loop if I want to play again. Also when I am prompted to play again I want to return to the beginning of the while loop but I can't seem to call on that function. I need help! Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BlackJack
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        char play = 'y';
        char drawAgain;
        int card1, card2;
        int nextCard = 0;


        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random number = new Random();


        while (play != 'n')
        {
            card1 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;
            card2 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;

            System.out.print("First cards: ");
            System.out.println(card1 + ", " + card2);
            int cardTotal = card1 + card2;
            System.out.println("Total: " + cardTotal);
            System.out.print("Draw again? (y/n): ");
            drawAgain = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

            while (drawAgain != 'n')
            {
                int card3 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;
                System.out.println("Card: " + card3);
                cardTotal += card3;
                System.out.println("Total: " + cardTotal);

                if (cardTotal <= 21) {
                    System.out.print("Draw Again? (y/n): ");
                    drawAgain = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

                }

                if (cardTotal > 21) {
                    System.out.println("Bust");
                    System.out.print("Would you like to play again? (y/n): ");
                    play = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                }


            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *" that character only should prompt a card draw*" but your code is not checking for that `while (play != 'n')`. Nowhere in your code you're checking for `'y'`.

Comment: @mattsap I think the outer while is the "main menu". Anyway, that's not the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with this code.

1. You will incur an infinite for loop because the drawAgain is never reset to n if the the points value is > 21.
2. In order to enforce the user must specify either a yes or no, you must check for it. Below does so with a while loop.
3. The play variable is never reset which forces the user to play until busting, then choose if want to keep playing or not.

The below addresses these issues. This should be what you want.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BlackJack
{
public static char getValidInput(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = keyboard.next();
    while(!input.equals("yes") || !input.equals("no")){

        System.out.println("please input yes or no");
        input = keyboard.next();
    }
    return input.charAt(0);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    char play = 'y';
    char drawAgain;
    int card1, card2;
    int nextCard = 0;


    Random number = new Random();

    while (play != 'n')
    {
        card1 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;
        card2 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;

        System.out.print("First cards: ");
        System.out.println(card1 + ", " + card2);
        int cardTotal = card1 + card2;
        System.out.println("Total: " + cardTotal);
        System.out.print("Draw again? (y/n): ");


        drawAgain = getValidInput();
        while (drawAgain != 'n')
        {
            int card3 = number.nextInt(10) + 1;
            System.out.println("Card: " + card3);
            cardTotal += card3;
            System.out.println("Total: " + cardTotal);

            if (cardTotal <= 21) {
                System.out.print("Draw Again? (y/n): ");

                drawAgain = getValidInput();
            }else{ //if (cardTotal > 21) {
                System.out.println("Bust");
                drawAgain ='n';
            }
        }
        play = getValidInput();
    }
}
}
```